Automating Advanced 2D Animations for Videos Similar to This Example Using Python
I am looking to automate the creation of videos with advanced 2D animations and transitions similar to the style shown in this YouTube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMDt-AWRMuM).
I understand that tools like Adobe Premiere Pro combined with plugins such as Type Monkey can be used for this kind of work. However, I am wondering if there is a way to achieve a similar result programmatically using Python.
Specifically, I am interested in:
Automating text animations, transitions, and effects.
Handling keyframing for smooth transitions.
Potentially exporting the final video file.
Are there any Python libraries, frameworks, or workflows that could help achieve this? Would using libraries like manim, MoviePy, or integrating Python with animation software (e.g., After Effects via scripting) be feasible?
Any guidance or examples to help me get started would be greatly appreciated!
